# Should I return something?

Tags: javascript

In javascript methods, I usually don't return anything if I don't have to. But then a question poped up. How does javascript clears the memory if I don't return anything? I know that JS uses garbage collector..so..somehow it clears memory for me. So my actual question is, is it considered a BETTER practice to return true or false even in those situations you don't expect any return values such as the following?

```
// assuming we get birthday in mm/dd/year format
function setAge( birthDay )
{
    var _birthdaySplited = birthDay.split("/");
    this.age = new Date().getFullYear() - parseInt( _birthdaySplited[2] );

    // should I say..return true here?
}
```

Comment: "How does javascript clears the memory if I don't return anything?" Clear *what* memory?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a function "returning" void (nothing). In fact, if the function isn't meant to return anything and only complete some action, then it *shouldn't* return anything. Void is void is void. Returning something that's not needed just confuses people.

Comment: How does a restaurant know you're done eating? Generally they'll start cleaning up the table when you walk about the door, and know you've not walked out the door yet because your coats (or you yourself) are still sitting at the table.

Comment: I wonder who thinks this is a good question, it doesn't really make sense in my head

Comment: You could include try-catch, returning true on success, false on failure, this would enable easy error handling with "if setAge, {continue code}, else {show error message}"

Comment: @NoBugs ...what? OP asks about garbage collection.

Comment: *"I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question."* -- Charles Babbage

Comment: It should be clear to you by now that you don't need a return statement just for the sake of having one. But regarding your `setAge()` function, if it's possible that it might receive a date in an invalid format then you should add validation and return true or false to indicate success or failure (or perhaps throw an exception on failure - don't do both).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it considered a BETTER practice to return true or false even in those situations you don't expect any return values such as the following?

### No.

> How does javascript clears the memory if I don't return anything?

Not explicitly returning a value has effectively zero impact on garbage collection. I'm not sure why you think it might.

Comment: Would it be useful to also mention that not explicitly returning anything causes the function to return `undefined` -- wouldn't you just be swapping one return value for another.  and +1 btw

Comment: I don't think it's hugely relevant. The OP seems confused about GC in general.

Answer (score 6):

Even if you don't return anything, javascript runtime knows that function finished executing and it now may clean up after it. Returning some dummy value won't do any help here.